# CodeIgniter: Why does my array of unique table data contain no values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

My database definitely contains values and I am trying to read these values for a specific column (name) into an array like so:

```
public function listcli()
{
 $this->db->distinct();
 $this->db->select('name');
}
}
```

then referencing to this function like so:

```
public function clist() {
    $this->load->model('list_model');
    $fields = $this->list_model->listcli();
    $fieldl = $fields;
    $data= array();
    $data['fieldl'] = $fieldl;
    $this->load->view('clientlist', $data);
    }
```

This basically completes the database query in the model, passes the information into the controller where it puts the array into another array with a key (key being the same name as the array) so that I can pass it into my view, then my view which looks like this :

```
<html>
<body>
    <p> <?php print_r($fieldl); ?></p>
    <ul>
        <?php
            $fieldl = array();
            ?>
            <p> <?php print_r($fieldl); ?> </p>
            <?php
            foreach($fieldl as $l) {
        ?>
            <li> 
                <?php echo $l;?>
            </li>
            <?php
            }
```

Then lists it

but even though I KNOW I have data in "name" the print_r is showing that my array is empty? Help please and thank you!

Comment: `listcli` doens't return a value?

Comment: Nope, that's the issue I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your model is returning any value? If not, the return some:

```
public function listcli()
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('name');
    return $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array(); // return value
}
```

Comment: That outputted this

CI_DB_pdo_result Object ( [num_rows] => 0 [conn_id] => PDO Object ( ) [result_id] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sales_lead ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [row_data] => ) 

Sorry I am a newbie to codeigniter.

Comment: @seanyt123 `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sales_lead` yielded 0 rows basically, try to comment distinct line, are you sure about the distinct

Comment: woops that is my database name, I entered my table name and got:

CI_DB_pdo_result Object ( [num_rows] => 2 [conn_id] => PDO Object ( ) [result_id] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT DISTINCT name FROM clients ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [row_data] => ) 

It should yield results though

Comment: @seanyt123 thats the db name? haha, check my revision

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
 public function listcli(){
     $this->db->distinct(); 
     $this->db->select('name');
     $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
     return ($query->num_rows > 0 ? $query->result() : array());
 }
```

If it does not help ... 
Please give me table structure with some dummy date, So that I can help you resolve this.